# Zephyr vs Test Rail vs QTest

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-management

My workplace needs to move away from manual excel spreadsheets. The solution we choose must meet these conditions:

1. support automated tests
2. suitable for small testing team
3. cost effective
4. can integrate with JIRA

What are the advantages and disadvantages of Zephyr, TestRail, and QTest as test management tools especially with these conditions?

Comment: I have edited the post to be less opinion-based. You may also want to look at the answers to https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17562/zephyr-vs-xray-vs-testrail?rq=1 and some of the other related questions.

Comment: option 3 doesn't have enough info.  solution for garage startup different to $10bn operation

Answer (score 1):

Test management tool is a software, right? If we need a new software, what do we do in the industry? We creat list of requirements, we prioritise them, then we evaluate and make a decision.

Additional questions to think about:

- How many people are in your testing team ("small team" means 2 or 10 people)?
- Who else will use your tool, need to have an access to it?
- How big is your budget for the tool? Do you have the budget for
  training or you will self-learn?
- Who will maintain the tool? A budget for that?
- What kind of other tools do you already use? Requirement tool maybe?
- What kind of features should have your TM tool? Only management of test cases and reporting or something more advanced?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Test Link** as Open source test management tool .Integrate Jira to Test link for posting bugs is easy. Testlink we can keep our automation scripts for test cases.

**JIRA** you can create Separate Project for test management .we need to create Issue type as Test case , configure the fields for test ,case template create workflow for test case management and integrate issue type and work flow to the Test Management Project

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend Zephyr, especially if you use Jira Cloude, not Jira standalone server. It's slow, with many limitation and it does not have so many usefully features as new products/plugins have. Zephyr for Jira Cloude has even more limitations. Furthermore, it's perhaps most expensive test management plugin for Jira. Take a look at [Xray](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xpandit.plugins.xray/server/overview), it looks very nice. I haven't use it in practice, but there is a public demo and you can try it yourself for free. Xray has  many good features and in my opinion it can be a very nice tool.

I've forgotten to mention: it's cheaper than Zephyr

Comment: How are you able to say that "it can be a very nice tool" if you "haven't used it"?

Comment: I said I have not used it in a practice, in a real project, but I have used a demo. The demo is available public and you do not must setup Jira instance.

Answer (score 0):

TestRail and Zephyr both offer great benefits when it comes to managing complex architectures of testing.

Being a part of a qa testing companies, I prefer Testrail over Zephyr for its ease of use and also meets your requirement:-

1. Cost Effective
2. Integration with JIRA
3. Suitable for small or large size team.
4. Integrate Automated tests
5. Ability to import existing test cases from Excel sheets